# Sending e-mail from computer on network - .NET 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, system.net.mail

I am trying to create a small desktop app that sends out e-mails to people in the office (all internal).  My application would run on a PC that is also on the network and the user will have outlook running for his own e-mails.

I'm looking at several examples where you need the SmtpClient and it needs to equal a host.  Is there a way that I can just set it to use the local machine?

```
                MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage("admin@network.com",
                reader["recipientAddress"].ToString(), "Subject", "Body");
                SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
                SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
```

I read that 127.0.0.1 is the local machine.  Would this work, or is there a different way of going about this?

Also would my messages go out if it sent a message to an external email?

Comment: Is the local machine running an SMTP server?

Comment: I'm not sure.  all I know is that it is connected to the network and the machine has Outlook as the e-mail client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install a SMTP server on your localhost to be able to send mail.

Outlook only receives e-mails through POP3 or IMAP, etc.

edit:
i.e. you need

1. some server that accepts mail through SMTP from your client and forwards it to its destination; and
2. some server that accepts mail (normally through SMTP) and stores it in a mailbox, so people can retrieve them later through POP3 or IMAP or whatever means.

Your company mail server should normally do both.

---

edit2:

You might be able to cheat and use `SMTPClient` to deliver the mail to the receiver's mailbox server directly though.

Try resolving for the MX record (see [How to get mx records for a dns name with System.Net.DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns)) and create a `SMTPClient` directly to the best MX server returned.

If Microsoft implemented enough of the SMTP specification and your host is not treated as sending spam, the mail should go through.

Comment: If I want to send out e-mails can I do it through POP3?

Comment: Unfortunately not, POP3 is for retrieving mail only. It's a polling system instead of pushing, i.e. the mail has to be there to be retrieved when the client connects and you can't push messages to client. If you want to do this in your program, you'll have to implement the POP3 protocol and a store for the messages generated before, which is non-trivial. Thus the easiest way is to find some simple SMTP server and install it locally if you don't want to use an external SMTP service. Alternatively write a simple client to replace the role of outlook...