# How to check an email address exists?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to check whether an email address exists, or not. I can verify `@gmail.com` addresses against the SMTP server `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`, but I do not know how to get the SMTP server for other domains, to check against. Please advise how to get the SMTP server of a domain, or alternatively another way to reliably check if email addresses exist.

This is my code to check `@gmail.com` addresses:

```
TcpClient tClient = new TcpClient("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);'
string CRLF = "\r\n";
byte[] dataBuffer;
string ResponseString;

NetworkStream netStream = tClient.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

/* Perform HELO to SMTP Server and get Response */
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO AnkurHere" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

dataBuffer = BytesFromString("MAIL FROM:<abc@gmail.com>" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();

/* Read Response of the RCPT TO Message to know from google if it exist or not */
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("RCPT TO:<" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + ">" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);

ResponseString = reader.ReadLine();
if (GetResponseCode(ResponseString) == 550)
   {
       label1.Text = "Mai Address Does not Exist !";
       label2.Text = "Original Error from Smtp Server" + ResponseString;
   }

/* QUITE CONNECTION */
dataBuffer = BytesFromString("QUITE" + CRLF);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
tClient.Close();
```

Comment: Your Google Apps SMTP server will depend on the country in which the domain was registered with Google. You are currently checking the India SMTP servers. Are all the domains registered with Google India? In addition, even if using Google Apps for email, you can still use the default Gmail servers for SMTP login. Be sure to use the full email address for the user's account.

Answer (score 0):

For the approach you are making, you will need to make a DNS lookup for the MX record of the domain. As far as I am aware, there is no built in way in .NET to do this, so you'll either have to find a component or take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns/7546721#7546721).

However you need to be advised that this method will not give 100% accurate results and may give false positives - some domains will accept a message for any address before either putting it into a "catch all" mailbox, silently deleting it or sending a bounce message. Accepting then bouncing is not a best practice but it does still occur on occasion.