# VB.net Send Email without knowing SMTP

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I want to send an e-mail without knowing SMTP.

I mean, i want my users to mail me through my soft, but the problem is that i don't know their @mail, then i don't know SMTP either.

I'm stuck here, thanks !

Comment: You want to send e-mails through your software but you know you don't have the required information? Whats the question?

Comment: The question is is there any way to send an email without knowing SMTP. I wrote it 2 times already ;) I mean can i know smtp with @mail, like "test@gmail.com" gives "smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: To send an email you're better off using your own SMTP server (or allow the user to set their own); I wouldn't advise trying to use the recipient's SMTP server as this is often not allowed and thus unreliable. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806778/how-to-get-the-smtp-server-from-email-address as this may help.

Comment: If you intend on having your program deliver the mail directly to the recipients server, you can look up mx records using DNS but I wouldn't rely on the user being allowed to send mail out of the network using SMTP. In a business environment, this will likely be restricted to their own smtp servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way may be to send an email through their own email client.

This code will open their default mail client and populate it with the specified adress subject and body:

```
    Dim address As String = "reg@gmail.com"
    Dim subject As String = "Help"
    Dim body As String = "Please help me with this error"

    Process.Start(String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}", address, subject, body))
```

Comment: I've seen this in other threads, but i'd have really want mails to be sent inside my soft

Comment: Send it from yourself? Then you don't have to worry about junk popping up for them, it works great!