# How can I retrieve the SMTP server from the users email address?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm programming a email sending program in C# 
The user gives his email address, and also the email address from the
reciever.

How can I retrieve the SMTP server from the users email address?

For example:
The user gives "user7712279@gmail.com". And I need to find the SMTP server "smtp.gmail.com". But for Yahoo, Hotmail, and other email services, it must work also. How can I do that?

Comment: What will you do with the smtp server once you find it? You cannot send mail on behalf of another unless you have their credentials.

Comment: It would be better if you try something... anything... then post your code when you hit a problem. We might be able to help you overcome specific issues, but we can't write your code for you.

Comment: You should explain what you want to do as a next step. The SMTP server addresses for a domain are retrieved via a DNS query for its MX records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the SMTP server from email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806778/how-to-get-the-smtp-server-from-email-address)

Comment: Could you explain (as an edit to your question) why you need that server's address? What do you want to do once you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve an SMTP server from an email address. It could be sent from basically **any** SMTP server regardless of the email address.

Additionally, most SMTP servers require some for of authentication and you would need to have the necessary credentials for all SMTP servers.

In general, when sending emails from your own application, you would need **one** SMTP server which you own or pay which you would use to send emails.