# Get DNS TXT record

Tags: c#, dns, mono, unity-game-engine

I want to lookup a TXT record in C# - in particular I want to do it from Unity3d (so basically mono 2.1 I think, as opposed to full fledged .NET). I don't require any other fancy DNS stuff, and it's for an app that I'd prefer not to get too bloated, so I'm preferably looking for something that doesn't require some huge library.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [*How to get mx records for a dns name with System.Net.DNS?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns).

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing built in even in full .Net framework to get [TXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) or any other DNS record except actual DNS resolution.

[DNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Dns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is the only one that deals with DNS and it only provides mapping of IP to name and reverse.

You will need to find a library or construct request directly. Consider checking out existing samples like [DNS Resolver article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23673/DNS-NET-Resolver-C) as starting point.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET use this nuget package.

P.S. I'm **not affiliated**, but we do use it in our project

Answer (score 0):

Based on DnsDig project I created a DLL which can be used on any .net (vb , c#, forms, web. etc..) project

https://devselz.com/software/devselz_dnsdig_dns-txt-etc-query-domain-register.zip

Download, unzip, and Add as reference to your project (if website place on root/bin folder:

#### DnsDig.dll

#### nunit.framework.dll

(126KB in total)

Then use this example as for an ASP.Ne website (vb.net code)

```
Imports DnsDig
Imports Heijden.DNS
Partial Class lib_u_l_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Resolver As Resolver
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Resolver = New Resolver
        Dim SW As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
        SW.Start()
        Dim DNSResponse As Heijden.DNS.Response = Resolver.Query(Request.QueryString("d"), QType.TXT, QClass.ANY)
        SW.Stop()
        If DNSResponse.header.ANCOUNT > 0 Then
            For Each answerRR As AnswerRR In DNSResponse.Answers
                Response.Write("<br/>" & answerRR.ToString)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```