# Get all DNS records

Tags: c#, dns

I'm looking for a way to get all DNS records by web address.
Is there a way to do this with C#, without any library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mx records for a dns name with System.Net.DNS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns)

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik I don't want to use any libary.

Comment: the second answer doesn't use any

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not really easy without any library.

You can use native code though, `DnsQueryEx` is a good starting point... 
You'll need tons of code to get it working in C# though.

Why not just use an existing library?

I just wrote one for donet core /xplat support for example:
https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET

which is really straight forward to use

```
var lookup = new LookupClient();
var result = await lookup.QueryAsync("google.com", QueryType.ANY);

var record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
var address = record?.Address;
```

See also http://dnsclient.michaco.net for more details/docs

Comment: QueryType.Any almost always never returns any record in AllRecords collection, am I looking in wrong direction

Comment: @Muds depends on the DNS server, most public servers will not return anything anymore for ANY requests. The query type is getting deprecated. Selfhosted DNS servers can also be configured to not answer ANY requests.

Comment: Thanks MichaC much appreciated!

Comment: I get 0 records on sendgrid.com, probably similar issue for other domains

Comment: I only get 1 answer, I know google.com has more than 1 ip address, how do I tell it to fetch them all?

Comment: Yes I also want to get all the entries. not just the primary dns one

Comment: you cannot explicitly ask for "all" IPs, if the DNS server you use decides to only return the first entry, it is what it is. That being said, if you do not use ANY but ask for A and AAAA records, you should get all IP and IPv6 addresses defined for a zone (if any)