# How to get the port number and host name of an email address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, email

I've a requirement where the user enters his email address and password and he should be able to send the emails through the application.

So to do that, if he enters an email address with the custom domain how to figure out his email's port number and host name.

For example, for gmail Id,

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMesaage.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
mailMesaage.Subject = "Test";
mailMesaage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMesaage.To.Add(to@gmail.com);

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```

But here is my doubt,

If the users email ID is "from@customdomain.com",
What would be the Host and Port for the above custom domain email ID!?

```
smtp.Host = "?";
smtp.Port = "?";
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the from email address and the smtp server. You can use your choice of smtp server without worrying about what is the email address of the sender. There is no way you can know the tcp port of email domain.

Comment: An email address doesn't have a host or port. But you could try to [query the MX record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns) of the domain of the from e-mail address. That might give you a server address. For the posts, leave the standard ones. Or prompt the user to override this settings, then it's up to them, to figure out, what they want.