# How to check if domain with tld ending is a real domain or a local one

Tags: c#, .net, networking, .net-core, dns

I'm doing a program where I have to work with email addresses, given by the user.

The application should also work with local email severs.

Because some companies use local email addresses like john.doe@deployment.mycompany, so my question is, how can I determine whether a given email address is local or public available.

This is the code for checking the IP address which seems to work nice, however, I want it to also work with domain names. Any ideas how I can do that?

```
        public static bool IsLocal(string host)
        {
            try
            {
                var hostIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

                var localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

                foreach (var hostIP in hostIPs)
                {
                    if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(hostIP)) return true;

                    foreach (var localIP in localIPs)
                    {
                        if (hostIP.Equals(localIP)) return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: maybe see if you can query for [MX record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) on that domain?

Comment: @timur I read that you need a DNS server for this, is that correct?

Comment: no, i was thinking a DNS client

Comment: @timur Okay, but is there any simple solution in .Net or do I have to use a thrid party library?

Comment: i just quickly found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669841/how-to-get-mx-records-for-a-dns-name-with-system-net-dns) - not sure if it will fit your "no third party library" criteria though

Comment: "is ending tld a real domain" and "is email address publicly available" are two very different questions". For the former, just querying one of the root DNS servers for NS record of top tld (and checking if the response is NXDOMAIN) should be enough.